# decrementar valor input dinamico apartir de un valor x - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

buen dia, necesito que al colocar un valor x en el input principal que se envie el valor al primer input dinamico y al darle en el menos que comience a decrementar el valor hasta que llegue a 1.

Tengo el siguiente código donde  tengo el input principal , el boton de enviar y los input se van creando de forma dinamica pero aun no he podido que el valor se envie al primer input dinamico y que desde ahi comience a decrementar hasta llegar a 1.

```js
import { useState } from "react";

const defaultState = {
  nombre: ""
};
function Row({ onChange, onRemove, nombre }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={nombre}
        onChange={e => onChange("nombre", e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Decrementar"
      />
      
      <button onClick={onRemove}>Eliminar</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default function Pruebas() {

  const [rows, setRows] = useState([defaultState]);

  const handleOnChange = (index, name, value) => {
    const copyRows = [...rows];
    copyRows[index] = {
      ...copyRows[index],
      [name]: value
    };
    setRows(copyRows);
  };

  const handleOnAdd = () => {
    setRows(rows.concat(defaultState));
  };

  const handleOnRemove = index => {
    const copyRows = [...rows];
    copyRows.splice(index, 1);
    setRows(copyRows);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
    <input type="number" name="pricipal" placeholder="Agregar valor" /> <button >Enviar</button> < br/> < br/>

      {rows.map((row, index) => (
        <Row
          {...row}
          onChange={(name, value) => handleOnChange(index, name, value)}
          onRemove={() => handleOnRemove(index)}
          key={index}
        />
      ))}
      <button onClick={handleOnAdd}>-</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: ¿Que has intentado? No hay ningún `handler` en el botón enviar.

Comment: he intentado que el input se decremente  de forma automatica pero no he encontrado la logica , me podrias ayudar?